# Supabase Serverside Datafetching share state with children Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, react-context, next.js13, supabase, zustand

Can somebody explain to me what the best way of sharing states between a server component and child components is?

I am recursively creating a file system type structure in Next.js 13 / react. My approach is to fetch the data in the parent server component and but I would like to use it across all the children.
Since the whole thing is recursive and there are many different components being rendered its just super messy to do prop-drilling. I thought of using a useContext() or zustand but from what I see, they are all only working on the client side, so how do I make a call to my postgres supabase backend on the server and share it will all the direct children, or the entire app?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to do prop drilling, the only way is to import the store and use

```
store.dispatch() // useDispatch
store.getState() // useSelecter
```

but this is anti pattern because

- it becomes challenging to unit-test those components in isolation. You cannot easily provide mock stores or simulate different state scenarios for testing purposes. With using hooks like useDispatch, you can easily mock the store and control the state for testing.
- When you directly import the store, you tightly couple your components to the store's implementation details.
- Redux DevTools Extension can help you trace actions and state changes more effectively if you use hooks

Comment: Ok that sucks. Am I misunderstanding something here entirely? It doesn't really make sense to me. From what I am reading in the docs, Next.js has extended the fetch api to basically cache the response so I could wrap my client components far down the component trees with another Server Component and then pass a prop down one layer only. But what if I use axios? or in my case use await supabase.rpc('xyz')

Comment: Caching available only for fetch not axios or supabase