# How to use redux tool-kit with Next.js 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, redux

In order to use redux I need to wrap nearly my entire app in a redux provider. This provider must be a client component. Now virtually my entire app is a child of a client component. Does this mean that none of them can be server components? This quote is in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#using-client-components-in-nextjs), "This means that by defining a "use client" in a file, all other modules imported into it, including child components, are considered part of the client bundle - and will be rendered by React on the client." If I'm understanding this correctly then if I wrap my app in a redux provider then all of my app will be client components. Am I not understanding this correctly? If this is true then what is a good way to manage the global state in Next.js 13 so that I can still use server components whenever I need them?

Answer (score 0):

this is your layout if you set up `redux` in `next.js13`

```
 <body className={inter.className}>
    <GlobalProvider>
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </GlobalProvider>
```

The client component can render server components if they are passed as children prop.  you can read this: [Does 'use client' in Next.js 13 root layout make whole routes client component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74992326/does-use-client-in-next-js-13-root-layout-make-whole-routes-client-component/75480826#75480826)

`children` here represents the rest of your project and it does not make server component client, server component is still a server component.

Before next.js 13 we used to use `next-redux-wrapper` library which creates the store on the server and ships it to the client and the client was recreating the client store with the shipped data. but `next-redux-wrapper` is not compatible with next.js13. you can still reach the redux store in server component by importing global store but this is not recommended. I explained here why: [Supabase Serverside Datafetching share state with children Next.js 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77169099/supabase-serverside-datafetching-share-state-with-children-next-js-13/77169207#77169207)

recommended way to reach the redux store or dispatch actions is to use hooks which are available only on client components